# How can i create a customize UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to create a `UIViewController` with an `UITableView` on the top and two `UIButton` on the middle and A `UITableView` on the bottom different with the other `UITableView` one the top like below

[image]

[image: -]

Comment: And I want a Porsche and a Rocket.

Comment: i'm going to edit it with "can i"

Comment: Now the question is: have you tried on your own? This should be rather trivial with all the guidance Xcode gives you. Add a UIViewController and modify its xib file or the main storyboard file (in iOS5).

Comment: but storyboard doesn't work for iOS5

Comment: @GoldFire Pretty sure Storyboards do indeed work for iOS5 since I'm using them ;)

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me like a single table view, with three sections, assuming that the second image is the first one scrolled up - if it were three separate parts then you wouldn't be able to scroll the top sections off the screen.

You'll need to create your own custom cells for the three sections.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one tableView instead of two, and set the `tableHeaderView` to a view that looks like a cell, and two buttons below. Check the image for reference:

[image]

It's easy to set this up on Interface Builder, and then you can use Quartz to get rounded corners. Have a look at this screenshot that I did really quick:

[image]

Comment: But how can i set the tableHeaderView like UITableViewCell like that?

Comment: Have a look to my updated answer. The first view under the table view is the tableHeaderView, with the background set to 'Group Table View Background'.

Answer (score 0):

open xcode

create new project or go to your existing project

go to file>new>new file

select `UIViewController` subclass

give it a name and make sure the bottom line says "Subclass of: `UIViewController`"

after that click next and create

you will get three new files all named the same but with different extensions

select the one with .xib extension

you will see whats called Interface Builder come up with a view

from here you can drag and drop other views into it (such as a tableview) from the list at the bottom right